# How to prevent a Microsoft List from reading a blank row from Power Automate

Tags: list, power-automate

I have been testing a Microsoft Automated Flow that reads data from a CSV.  To begin with, the flow is supposed to try to find a corresponding match in the "Title" column (so that the Title in a row in the List matches the Title in a row in the CSV file).  When this happens, the corresponding row in the List is updated with the row information in the CSV file.

Now, here is the problem: there are now blank rows in the LIST.  I do not understand how this could happen.  I have seen in the past a situation where a CSV file can have a blank row from a edit mistake in EXCEL.  When this happens, if you edit the CSV file in a text editor, you will see a row of commas depicting a row of blank cells.  But I checked each CSV file I have used in my tests and none of them have one of these rows.

So what is going on here and how can I fix it?  What could be causing these blank rows in my List?

[image: blank-rows.PNG]

If the CSV file is opened in a text file, I can put the cursor on the line after the last line.  Maybe there is an issue with representing the return character '/r'.  But there is more.

I looked up another flow that I had worked on and found this:

[image: something-to-try-to-remove-blank-line.png]

This flow has a filter which takes the output from a previous step and filters out a line that equals to nothing.

But the flow I am wanting to apply this do does not have a previous step of converting the CSV to an array.  The logic of my new flow is different.

[image: new-logic.png]

Where can I insert logic where a blank line is ignored?

If I investigate this flow that has completed a run, I see this which is an indication that the new line was read into the flow:

[image: line-found.png]

If there is not a way to filter that out, there is the next step:

[image: another-place.png]

Comment: Split the data up so you have a different item in an array by line and then filter them out that way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Filter Array` step in-between your
`Compose - split by new line`
<-- inset here -->
`Compose - get field names`

With the following:

```
From: outputs('Compose_-_new_line')
Condition (advanced mode): @not(equals(item(), ''))
```

Then update your `Compose - get field names` step to reference the new filter step.